# atom html preview: doesn't respond to Angular controller

Tags: angularjs, atom-editor

I'm using Atom editor to write some Angular code and I watch the preview HTML window to see how my looks.

I wrote the following controller:

```
  eventsApp.controller('EventController',
  function EventController($scope){
    $scope.event = {
      name: "Angular",
      date: '1/1/2013',
      time: '10:30 am'
    };
  });
```

and wrote this code in the html file:

```
<div class="container">
  <div ng-controller="EventController">
    {{event.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

The html preview window looked this way: 
[image]

Do you know what can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you might have missed writing `ng-app="eventsApp"` (or whatever your module name is..) in the parent div or maybe with the `body`.

Here's the same code working as expected: [codepen](http://codepen.io/tanmayrajani/pen/VKEvWa)

If you've already added `ng-app`, check for a typo or something. Make sure Angular and your app's script (if not inline) are loaded properly.

Edit: Here's your example on atom-preview. Works as expected.

[image: atom html preview]